# Scaling up PDFs

Tags: print-design, print-production, digital-printing

If I've prepared an A4 print doc, that consists of vector graphics and also a large jpeg background... will the vectors scale up properly if I print the doc at A2?

I understand that the jpeg background would become pixellated, but I dont mind too much about that as it's only a subtle texture.

But the vectors are .ai files that are placed into the document... I imagine those should be fine if printing the PDF at double the size?

Or would I actually need to turn the PDF into an A2 document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector content is vector content.

It doesn't matter if that vector content is in a PDF file, and EPS file, an AI file, and Indd file.. it's all vector and all behaves the same upon scaling.

So, **yes**. Vector content in a PDF will be infinitely scalable without quality loss like all vector content.